# How to extract files from uImage?

Tags: embedded, images, compression, u-boot, buildroot

Buildroot is generating images for an embedded device where they should run. This is working very well. In those images, the rootfs is included.

Due to some research, I'd like to look into that generated file (e.g. different compression modes set by the Buildroot were applied and now shall be checked if they were correctly done), but I can't find something useful in the Net.

As far as I know, the difference between a uImage and zImage is just a small header, so u-boot is able to read that binary file. But I can open neither uImage nor the zImage.

Can anyone give me a hint of how to decompress those (u/z)Images on the host?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
mkimage -l uImage
```

Will dump the information in the header.

```
tail -c+65 < uImage > out
```

Will get the content.

```
tail -c+65  < uImage | gunzip > out
```

will get it uncompressed if it was gzip-compressed.

If that was an initramfs, you can do `cpio -t < out` or `pax < out` to list the content.

If it's a ramdisk image, you can try and mount it with:

```
mount -ro loop out /mnt
```

`file out` could tell you more about what it is.

Comment: Header tells me that it's an: ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed). i can't open it neither with gunzip nor cpio the way that you explained it. Mounting the image wasn't possible too

Comment: @user3085931, then that's a kernel image not a filesystem. You  can't do anything with it except boot it. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: but the rootfs is included. I use the 3 different compression modes and for one of them it's not working, therefore my plan was to open the image and check what has bin compressed

Comment: @user3085931, if the rootfs has been appended to the kernel image, then somehow the offset must be specified somewhere either as parameters passed to the kernel or embeded in the kernel itself. Do you have an example of such an image somewhere?

Comment: i've been playing with one and it was compressed with lzma (`mkimage -l` reported `Image Type:   MIPS Linux Kernel Image (lzma compressed)`) so used unlzma to expand it

Comment: If you want to extract the rootfs to the current directory, run `tail -c+65 < rootfs.image.gz | cpio -i`. If the archive is compressed with gzip, run `tail -c+65 < rootfs.image.gz | gunzip | cpio -i`.

Answer (score 18):

U-Boot brings its own `dumpimage` tool (find it in the tools directory of your U-Boot tree)

Of course it works with simple images, but it also supports the old-style multi images

```
$ ~2/tools/dumpimage -l uMulti 
Image Name:   
Created:      Thu Aug 31 19:54:29 2017
Image Type:   ARM Linux Multi-File Image (uncompressed)
Data Size:    5678650 Bytes = 5545.56 kB = 5.42 MB
Load Address: 10008000
Entry Point:  10008000
Contents:
   Image 0: 5028760 Bytes = 4910.90 kB = 4.80 MB
   Image 1: 602111 Bytes = 588.00 kB = 0.57 MB
   Image 2: 47762 Bytes = 46.64 kB = 0.05 MB
$ ~2/tools/dumpimage -i uMulti kernel.extracted
$ ~2/tools/dumpimage -i uMulti -p 1 initramfs.extracted
$ ~2/tools/dumpimage -i uMulti -p 2 device-tree.extracted
```

Have not tried it with new style FIT images yet, but I guess it should just work.

Comment: It works with FIT images.

Comment: Fast forward to 2023, `dumpimage` does not have `-i` option now. You need to also provide the image type while extracting the image with option `-T`.

Answer (score 5):

In case there are several images inside here is a quick `bash` script to extract them all into the files `image_0`, `image_1`, …:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

src_file=uImage

declare -ia sizes=( $(mkimage -l "$src_file" |
  awk '/^ +Image [0-9]+/ { print $3 }') )
declare -i offset="68+4*${#sizes[@]}"
declare -i size

for i in "${!sizes[@]}"; do

  size=${sizes[$i]}

  echo "Unpacking image_$i"
  dd if="$src_file" of="image_$i" bs=1 skip="$offset" count="$size"

  # going to offset of next file while rounding to 4 byte multiple
  offset+=$(( size + (4 - size % 4) % 4 ))

done
```

You then need to check then what is what (could be a packed Linux kernel, archive with files, device tree, …). `file` and `binwalk` (http://binwalk.org/) might be helpful.

Comment: very nice addition

Answer (score 2):

`7z` "just works" for me, though this may be specific to OpenWRT and SquashFS. I tried it based on [a comment on the OpenWRT forums](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/how-to-extract-openwrt-firmware/4307/7).

```
$ file image.bin 
image.bin: u-boot legacy uImage, OpenWrt fullimage, Linux/MIPS, Multi-File Image (Not compressed), 11334834 bytes, Mon Apr 12 09:59:28 2021, Load Address: 00000000, Entry Point: 00000000, Header CRC: 0XDFDE3FF5, Data CRC: 0X7704142B

$ 7z x image.bin

7-Zip [64] 17.04 : Copyright (c) 1999-2021 Igor Pavlov : 2017-08-28
p7zip Version 17.04 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,16 CPUs x64)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 11334898 bytes (11 MiB)

Extracting archive: image.bin
--       
Path = image.bin
Type = SquashFS
Offset = 2097224
Physical Size = 9237674
Headers Size = 47040
File System = SquashFS 4.0
Method = XZ
Cluster Size = 262144
Big-endian = -
Created = 2021-04-12 04:59:26
Characteristics = DUPLICATES_REMOVED EXPORTABLE 0x600
Code Page = UTF-8

Everything is Ok                                        

Folders: 145
Files: 2518
Size:       36789620
Compressed: 11334898
```