# Can you unwrap an image prepared for Uboot using mkimage?

Tags: u-boot

I have an image that's currently wrapped in a uboot header from using the Uboot mkimage utility. I don't have the original of that image, so I want to take off the uboot header to turn the uimage back into a normal one. Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290421/117599 might interest you.