# U-BOOT error- data abort

Tags: u-boot

occurs here:

> reading initfs.image.gz
>
> data abort
>
> pc  : [<3ff5ae10>]         lr : [<3ff7c38c>]
>
> reloc pc : [<04024e10>]    lr : [<0404638c>]
>
> sp  : 3f314a78    ip : 00000000    fp : 00000000
>
> r10 : 000f0447    r9 : 3f315ee8    r8 : 00000030
>
> r7  : 000018c0    r6 : 00000020    r5 : 3f314a9c    r4 : 3f3164f8
>
> r3  : 000000a0    r2 : 000f0447    r1 : f3a900e3    r0 : 89a18e56
>
> Flags : nZCv IRQs off FIQs off Mode SVC_32
>
> Resetting CPU ...
>
> resetting ...

Don't really know what that the data abort error implies.

What was happening before this was Uboot is supposed to be copying the kernel image, device tree, and ramdisk into memory before calling bootm to those.

It looks like the kernel image and devicetree both were read fine, its when it gets to this 3rd thing that things go south.

After resetting, the startup goes just the same, gets to this point, and throws data abort again.

Comment: Is the boot image maybe damaged? Could you maybe try to unpack it, see [How to extract files from uImage?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113827/117599)

Comment: The uboot image does not seem to be damaged. I am working with 2 uramdisk.image.gz files, one of which boots properly, the other of which does not. The one that isn't working is supposed to be the same as the first ramdisk, but with a couple of added utilities and kernel modules which will be needed. So something is apparently wrong with the second ramdisk which is preventing it from being copied, but I don't know what.

Comment: Maybe something about the compression?

Comment: maybe? But I tried recompressing it, and compared it to the one that works with "file" and they both are the same, cpio archives.

Comment: Of the newc type?

Comment: PLease post a full log that includes the commands you're running, and since it sounds like you have a "works" and "doesn't work' case, include both.  Thanks!